# Code is working fine in jsfiddle, But not when saved locally

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following code for selecting only excel files. Check the functionality in the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/smashitjusty/g6KRq/11/). It is working fine in fiddle. But when saving in a notepad locally, this code is not working. **No jQuery** is used. Pure JavaScript.

Following is how I used in notepad.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var file = document.getElementById('browse');

        file.onclick = function(e) {
            var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
            switch (ext) {
                case 'xls':

                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                case 'xlsx':
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = 'Please choose .xls or .xlsx file';
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;

            }
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type='file' id="browse" name="browse" />
    <input type="submit" value="Import" id="button" disabled>
    <p id="new"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: did you get any error in console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check this code  http://jsfiddle.net/g6KRq/9/

```
<input type='file' id="browse" name="browse" onchange="checke(this)" />
<input type="submit" value="Import" id="button" disabled>
<p id="new"></p>
<script>
    function checke(e) {
        var ext = e.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];

        switch (ext) {
            case 'xls':

                document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                break;
            case 'xlsx':
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                break;
            default:
                document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = 'Please choose                   .xls or .xlsx file';
                document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;

        }
    };
</script>
```

Comment: That is completely fine. But what could be possibly wrong with my code.?

Comment: you wrote onclick event which will not help here, onChange event helps here

Comment: Even with `onchange` it wasnt working locally. The change you made is giving `onchange="checke(this)"` in input tag instead of the script. That made the change i guess.

Answer (score 1):

Please use onchange http://jsfiddle.net/g6KRq/4/.

As pointed out by @teddy, the script block should be below the `<input>` element.

```
    <html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type='file' id="browse" name="browse" />
    <input type="submit" value="Import" id="button" disabled>
    <p id="new"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var file = document.getElementById('browse');

        file.onchange = function(e) {
            var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
            switch (ext) {
                case 'xls':
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                case 'xlsx':
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = 'Please choose .xls or .xlsx file';
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;

            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

While we are at it, why not go a head and set the accept attribute ?

```
<input type='file' id="browse" name="browse" accept=".xls,.xlsx"  />
<input type="submit" value="Import" id="button" disabled>
<p id="new"></p>
```

Comment: Man. ! That was `onchange`. i edited to `onclick` for testing purpose.

Comment: The code works even if the `script` tag is above the `input` tag.

Comment: So your old code using `onchange` and with the `script` tag above the `input` tag works? What's the problem then?

Comment: I moved the `onchange` from function to `input` tag. And its working. Like @Karthick Kumar did.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using the onchange instead of the onclick event.
The onclick event might behave a bit odd and You don't need to fire the event if the user selects the same file.

In addition there is a simpler way of detecting the file extension:

```
var ext = this.value.split('.').pop();
```

I updated your [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smashitjusty/g6KRq/2/) accordingly:

```
var file = document.getElementById('browse');

file.onchange = function (e) {
    var ext = this.value.split('.').pop();
    switch (ext) {
        case 'xls':
            document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
            break;
        case 'xlsx':
            document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
            break;
        default:
            document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = 'Please choose                   .xls or .xlsx file';
            document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
    }
};
```

This should work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript block should always be included just before end of body tag, so that it doesn't block your web page. On click event triggers your event on click of button and that event ends before you are done with selecting file. So, you should use "onchange" event

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="browse" name="browse" />
    <input type="submit" value="Import" id="button" disabled>
    <p id="new"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var file = document.getElementById("browse");
        file.onchange = function(e) {
            var ext = file.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
            switch (ext) {
                case 'xls':
                case 'xlsx':
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = 'Please choose .xls or .xlsx file';
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;
            }
        };
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: JSFiddle's browser uses different browser standards so your code was running well in JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

The problem is: "Where do you put your script code?"

At first, the main difference between your local and fiddle is "script" block position:

- On your local, your script is put in head block
- On fiddle, the script is put onLoad

So, if you change script "Frameworks & Extensions" in fiddle to "No wrap - in head", you'll meet the same problem.

To fix this problem in your local, you have to put your script after the "browse" block.

i.e.

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>
    <input type='file' id="browse" name="browse" />
    <input type="submit" value="Import" id="button" disabled>
    <p id="new"></p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var file = document.getElementById('browse');

        file.onclick = function(e) {
            var ext = this.value.match(/\.([^\.]+)$/)[1];
            switch (ext) {
                case 'xls':

                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                case 'xlsx':
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = '';
                    break;
                default:
                    document.getElementById('new').innerHTML = 'Please choose .xls or .xlsx file';
                    document.getElementById('button').disabled = true;

            }
        };
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Further information, you should know that method document.getElementById only finding the generated element. So in head tag, there are no "browse" element found.
Might be you're too familiar with jQuery onLoad so forget these basic.

Comment: Thanks for that. But the code works both ways as well. What i mean is `script` tag before the `input`...